# Ошибка при отправке сообщения на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Есть такой код бота Telegram для отправки сообщения другому человеку на Python:

```
import telegram
import time

api_key = 'MyKEY'
user_id = 'Another_User_ID'

bot = telegram.Bot(token='MyKEY')

time.sleep(5)

bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text='Привет!')
```

При отправке на свой `user_id`,мне приходит сообщение, а при отправке другому человеку выдается ошибка:
`telegram.error.BadRequest: Chat not found`, хотя `user_id` верный

Подскажите в чем проблема. Спасибо

Comment: а разве айди чата иайди юзера это одно и тоже?

Comment: @finally, да, так как я свой ввожу и он мне пишет, в мой с ним чат

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Боты телеграм не могут инициировать чат, возможно, причина в этом. Пусть "другой человек" сам напишет боту, тогда бот сможет ответить.